# RDLC Report Height Dynamic Change

Tags: c#, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm working on RDLC Report and this will be printed on POS Printer. My problem is that I cannot set the height of the printer dynamically. This causes to print by chunk or with extra spaces on the paper. I need help. Thank you.

I already tried changing the Page Setting on LocalReport.GetDefaultPageSettings().PaperSize.Height but to no avail.